# Как избежать повторного выполнения скрипта?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Имеються проект на angular, а в нем вкладки с содержимым которое подгружается при переключении.

```
 <ul class="serv-tree-nav">
                        <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="auth.showRestricted"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 'favorites'})"><span class="pic favorites"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-10.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.FAVORITE' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 'all'})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-1.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.ALL_PAYMENTS' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.cardtocard"><span class="pic"><img src="../images/serv-tree-item-2.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.CARD_TO_CARD' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 33})" ng-click=""><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-3.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.MOBILE' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 44})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-4.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.HOSTING' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 39})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-5.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.WEBMONEY' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 34})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-6.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.INTERNET' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 40})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-7.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.GAMES' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 37})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-8.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.COMMUNAL' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 38})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-9.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.CREDIT' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ng-click="toService('nonContractExternal')"><span class="pic"><img src="../images/recvizits.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.RECVIZ' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="pages.services({categoryId: 'other'})"><span class="pic"><img class="svg-img" src="../images/serv-tree-item-11.svg" alt=""></span><span class="text">{{'PAYMENTS.OTHER' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

В контроллере есть скрипт jQuery который вытаскивает с тегов img - svg изображения, заменяет им картинку что бы дальше можно было при переключении по вкладкам, активной вкладке изменять цвет иконки.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.svg-img').each(function(){
            var img         = $(this);
            var image_uri   = img.attr('src');

            $.get(image_uri, function(data) {
                var svg = $(data).find('svg');
                svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
                img.replaceWith(svg);
            }, 'xml');

        });
    });
```

Проблема в том что при каждом переключении по вкладке, код выполняется заново и тем самым выполняет кучу запросов и нагружает network. (Не знаю как это обьяснить. В общем получается в отладке, во вкладке network много запросов). Как этого избежать?

Comment: это еще одна из причин, почему не рекомендуют использовать jquery вместе с ангуляром

Comment: та я другого решения не придумал для данной ситуации. может уже появилось что то новое для работы с СВГ ?

Comment: непонятно, зачем тебе тут jquery понадобился, это раз. Если у тебя должен быть один набор картинок - используй для хранения какой-нибудь сервис